# help changing trigger code to not only insert based on case status, but update if the case status has changed

Tags: apex, trigger, update

The trigger below works so that if a case is in the status of 'escalated', then a web service ticket is created. However, I need the trigger also create a web service ticket if the case status has been changed from anything TO 'escalated' status.

```
trigger SynchronizeWithJIRAIssue on Case (after insert) {

system.debug('trigger!');
//Identify profile name to be blocked from executing this trigger
String JIRAAgentProfileName = 'JIRA Agent2';
List<Profile> p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:JIRAAgentProfileName];

//new code
List<Case> escCases = new List<Case>();

//Check if specified Profile Name exist or not
if(!p.isEmpty()){
    //Check if current user's profile is catergorized in the blocked profile
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId()!= String.valueOf(p[0].id)){
        for (Case c : Trigger.new){
            //new code to check for escalated
            // all the cases that have status as 'Escalated' is added to a list called escCases
            if(c.Status == 'Escalated'){
                escCases.add(c);
            }
        }
        if(escCases != null && escCases.size()>0){
            // now iterate over the selected cases and call the web service
            for(Case c : escCases){
                //call webservice
                system.debug('inside case ' + c.CaseNumber);
                //Define parameters to be used in calling Apex Class
                String jiraURL = 'http://jira.hjkhjkhjkhjk5';
                String systemId = '2';
                String objectType ='Case';
                String objectId = c.id;
                String projectKey = 'LEV';
                String issueType = '27';
                System.debug('\n\n status is escalated');
                //Execute the web service call
                //warning - may result in breach of governer limits
                //sending cases in a list would be a better solution, but jira should have a corresponding operation
                JIRAConnectorWebserviceCallout.CreateIssue(jiraURL, systemId ,objectType,objectId,projectKey,issueType);
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange .Would like to request you to make an attempt before posting question here .Would love to help you here but trying to understand where are you stuck ?

Comment: The trigger that i posted works, but i also need it to create a new jira ticket (call to the web service) if an existing case changes to "Escalated". Right now, the trigger works so that if a new case is created with the status of "Escalated", then a ticket is created. We want to be able to have the trigger run so that if an existing case is, say, in a "On Hold" status, but is changed to "Escalated", for the trigger to  also fire.

Comment: if i do after insert, after update, then it creates hundreds of tickets

Comment: Actually, we got the trigger working now. The only thing that needs to change is that if there is a case that is already created, that it updates Jira (the web service) any time an edit is made to the original case. I was using the following documentation, but it wasn't working :(   https://docs.servicerocket.com/display/CFSJ/Synchronize+Endpoint+-+Developing+an+Apex+Class+and+Salesforce+Trigger+to+Automate+Synchronization+Process

Comment: i created a whole new class and trigger, based on that documentation, but then nothing fired. not sure where to go from here!

Answer (score 2):

For the update case, you can ignore all field changes except the specific status field change that you are interested in.

So the trigger would start like this to handle the update as well as the insert:

```
trigger SynchronizeWithJIRAIssue on Case (after insert, after update) {
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.Status == 'Escalated') {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                // Always update JIRA on an escalated insert
                cases.add(c);
            } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                Case old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
                if (c.Status != old.Status) {
                    // Only update JIRA on a change from any other status to escalated
                    cases.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (cases.size() > 0) {
        // Update JIRA for these Cases only using similar code to the existing
    }
}
```

If what is sent to JIRA needs to be different for the update and insert cases, the [trigger context variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) such as Trigger.isUpdate can be used to make the logic conditional.